# Where to find additional languages for Gimp?

Tags: language, gimp

I installed Gimp 2.8 with "Translations" option checked in in "Select Components" window during setup.

In Preferences › Interface, “System Language” is selected by default. The only other option available is “English [en_US]”.

Where can I download additional languages, like German or French, for Gimp?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @Sekhemty: I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro Preview with en-US as the default culture.

Comment: How many subdirectories do you have under `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\locale`. There all the language-subdirectories should be listed. ... Wow, you're right. I now (after installation) also have 2 languages ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest Gimp-release. (In 2.8.2 it was working. In 2.8.6 not)

To get Gimp in your language you can do the following:

- Goto `C:/Users/Username/.gimp-2.8` and open `gimprc` with a text-editor.
- If you have the line `(language "xx")` change the `xx` to the desired language.
  You need to look in the `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\locale` directory to see how your language is called.
- If the line `(language "xx")` is not there you can add it (or toggle the language to English one time in the `Preferences` after it will appear in `gimprc`).

This won't give you all the languages back in the pulldown but at least you have Gimp in your language.

Answer (score 0):

Same with Gimp-2.8.4 in Linux Mint 15 Olivia:

Resolved with editing ~/.gimp-2.8/gimprc :
Added line:

(language "fr")

Instead of "fr" you could set your language: de,ru,it,es, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the above procedure in Linux Mint 18 (Sarah) Cinnamon Beta but it did make it. Instead, I had to install the gnome language pack for my language (language-pack-gnome-fr, in my case, but you can change the two last letters according to your own language). Then I restarted Gimp and voilà. You may have to select your language in the Preferences > Interface menu if need be.

Comment: The additional language doesn't show up in `Interface` in my case after installing `language-pack-gnome-fr` after `Gimp` restart. I had to run `LANGUAGE=fr gimp` to start Gimp in the additional language (here French) [as documented by Gimp](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html#gimp-concepts-running-language).